# Mock Mongo, MongoDatabase.GetCollection and MongoCollection using Moq

Tags: mongodb, nunit, moq

Can any one please help me in mocking db.GetCollection of MongoDatabase to return mocked data using Moq

```
//returns MongoDatabase instance
var db = mongoConnector.Connect();

//Return Collection on the type Entity being passed
db.GetCollection<Entity>("CollectionName").AsQueryable().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing MongoDatabase sounds like an overkill. I would strongly recommend having data dependent integration tests for your data access layer. Test your core CRUD code using integration tests and clean up/bootstrap the database after each test run. Cleaning up the database on teardown is important as every test should be independent of other.

MOQ can be used to test the business logic layer in which you can mock the data access layer and return expected data instead of hitting the database.